# Tokenize the words based on a list

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I have a requirement of tokenizing the words in a sentence based on the specific word list.

```
wordlist = ["nlp - nltk", "CIFA R12 - INV"]
```

Example-input: This is sample text for  `nlp - nltk CIFA R12 - INV`.

while using word_tokenize(Exapmle-input), here I need `nlp - nltk` as one token and `CIFA R12 - INV` as another token. Is that possible rather than getting `nlp` `-` `CIFA` as different tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who comes here in future:-
After some reading, i have found out nltk.tokenize.mwe module is the option to achieve my above requirement.

Reference: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.mwe.html